# Why isn't my embedded style taking precedence over styles in my external stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

I have the following stylesheet:

```
/* MyStylesheet.css */
.MyForm .MyInput fieldset { border: 2px solid grey }
```

And then the following HTML code:

```
<div class="MyForm">
 <div class="MyInput">
  <fieldset>
   <style type="text/css">
    .MyInnerFieldsets fieldset { border: 0 }
   </style>
   <div class="MyInnerFieldsets">
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    </fieldset>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </div>
</div>
```

All fieldsets are receiving the 2px solid grey border from the external stylesheet. I thought the nested fieldsets would receive the 0 border from the embedded style, since the selector ".MyInnerFieldSets fieldset" takes precedence over ".MyForm .MyInput fieldset". I tested this in Firefox 3.6.8. Is this the expected behavior or is this a Firefox problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector

```
.MyForm .MyInput fieldset
```

has a greater *specificity* (is more specific) than the selector

```
.MyInnerFieldsets fieldset
```

A more specific selector overrides a less specific one.  [Read about specificity and how it's calculated here.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#specificity)

To solve it, make your second selector more specific (such as `.MyInput .MyInnerFields fieldset`), or make the first one less specific (`.MyInput fieldset`).

Comment: **Extra advice:** That is indeed the problem @thomasrutter, but before adding an extra selector I would actually rethink why that is needed in the first place. Since doing this gets you into CSS Specificity problems really quick. Why do you need to be so specific? Can you be less specific? I would recommend using something like BEM (or something like it) to make your life easier in the long run. https://getbem.com/introduction/

Comment: Yeah that's a good point, and you can quickly end up in a specificity war - and the next escalation in that war is `!important`... it gets ugly.  In this case, making the first one *less* specific is probably another option, since maybe you want your more general rule to apply to *any* fieldset in `.myform` and then want to single out exceptions - anyway there are plenty of ways to do it and CSS forces you to think of your own structure

Answer (score 0):

```
.MyForm .MyInput fieldset { border: 2px solid grey }
```

This rule has 2 classes specified, so it's more specific than the latter rule. Simply make the latter rule as specific or more specific by prepending it with the same class name.